# What are all the spells, items and hirelings that help with finding secrets and where can I obtain them?

Tags: might-and-magic-x-legacy

In Might and Magic X, it is kinda difficult if not impossible to find secret doors without the help of either spells or hirelings. Perception seems only to be needed for some kind of secret doors, but it does not help to find them.

Therefore, what are all the spells and tricks to find secret areas? Especially if you don't have a character capable of Dark Magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to detect secrets:

Rosalie from the Chapel of Elrath in Sorpigal detects secret doors (as well as enemies and traps).  While she is free, she only stays with the party until you complete the Highwaymen quest (which you have to complete to be able to move on).

The spell to find secrets is Whispering Shadows, an Expert Dark Magic spell.  You can also find scrolls of it in various places, though getting enough scrolls to discover all the secret doors would likely be extremely costly.

The most efficient way in the mid-game to find secrets is Spike, a dog that you rescue in the Forest of Yon-Chall.  However, he only helps you detect secret doors.  I'm not sure what happens if you dismiss him...I've read reports that you can't get him back.

The blessing of the Dark Dragon god, Malassa, also gives you the ability to detect secrets.

It's not exactly part of the question, but you should know that there are three stats that drive being able to open secret doors.  They are Might, Perception, and Magic.  While it's not hard to specialize at least 1 part member in order to cover all your bases, there are also a few other ways to boost these stats.  Inner Fire is an Expert Fire spell that boosts Might, Eagle Eye is an Expert Air spell that boosts Perception, and Hour of Power is a Grandmaster Primordial spell that boosts all 3 (as well as Destiny).  You can also find magic items that provide stat boosts.